# NoClassDefFoundError: org/jbox2d/collision/shapes/Shape in netbeans

Tags: playn

I am trying to add jbox2d as a dependency to my project in netbeans (playn-jbox2d-1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar), but at run time, I get:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jbox2d/collision/shapes/Shape

All other classes can be accessed fine, just not Shape.

I simply right clicked dependencies in my core directory and did add dependency and searched for jbox2d.

Anyone know what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of jbox2d do you have, as a dependency? You can crosscheck in the dependency jar file, if that class (Shape.class) exists or not?

EDIT: Most of the times, 'NoClassDefFoundError' happens due to incorrect classpath settings or when there's more than one class (or jar file) in the classpath, with the same namespace.

Comment: Shape.class does exist and I am using playn-jbox2d-1.1-SNAPSHOT

Comment: How would you fix your classpath settings?